# How to get a for function and lapply to read a file folder with data

Tags: r, function, for-loop, lapply

I cannot get my lapply function to read the files it just reads in years 2009's  file not the rest.  So how do I fix my code so that it reads in all the years from 2009-2016.

````
    library(dplyr)
setwd("C:/Users/Sarah/Downloads/ad_viz_plotval_data-")
    read.table(paste("ad_viz_plotval_data-", 2009, ".csv", sep = ""),
               header = TRUE, 
               sep = ",")

    Air <- function(i){
      for(i in 2009:2016){
        cnames <- read.table(paste("ad_viz_plotval_data-",i,".csv",sep = ""), 
                             header = TRUE,
                             sep = ",")
      }
    }



Using lapply, make a list containing a data.frame for each year.
```{r}
cnames1 <- lapply(2009:2016, Air)
f <- ldply(cnames1, data.frame)
````

Comment: `ldply` belongs to `plyr` package

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterate directly from `lapply`

```
files <- paste0("ad_viz_plotval_data-", 2009:2016, ".csv")
cnames1 <- lapply(files, read.csv)
f <- plyr::ldply(cnames1, data.frame)
```